# Helping a friend who will likely die without help, but refuses help?

Tags: friends, money, how-to-help, depression

So I have a friend who's suffering from a condition known as cirrhosis that will likely take their life anytime between several months from now and several years from now.

The thing is, this condition, unlike for example, late-stage cancer, isn't an unavoidable death knell; with the right procedures, this condition can be very much treated, if not outright cured.

But unfortunately, this friend of mine cannot afford these treatments any longer, and absolutely refuses most forms of help from others, especially money based help, simply because they think that taking other people's money to make their life better is being selfish, and that taking what they can't give back is against their moral code.

Worse still is that they've had a pretty miserable life overall (to the point that their miserableness had led to their condition), and they insist that their life would continue to be awful without this condition. In other words, I feel they're basically trying to commit "suicide by inaction".

I really don't want to lose them, and I feel more powerless than ever. Is there anything whatsoever I can do to get them the help they need?

Comment: I apologize if this question is shoddily formatted, as it was taken from another place I asked this (where I got no answers, much to my dismay) and slightly edited, and I'm rather panicky and stressed and I don't think I'm of the best mindset to try to appropriately format it, especially considering that I'm really not knowledgeable on how to format it for this site anyway...

Comment: I also decided to forgo the "suicide" tag, as from looking through the few questions on the tag, my situation would not fit it, despite the fact that I feel they're trying to commit suicide through unconventional means. Though if someone thinks that it's fine to add, please do let me know.

Comment: Hi! I can see that this is a very difficult situation. However, IPS helps answer questions that are aimed towards Interpersonal issues- is there an *interpersonal* goal you would like to achieve with this friend? Reading the question, one goal I see is that you want to help them financially but without disrespecting their wishes. Would that take place in a conversation? How often do you see the friend?

Comment: @SuperStew - Hey! I've noticed that you've left several chatty comments lately, or answers in comments. I'd like to make sure that you're aware that IPS enforces a strict policy on comments, and comments here are to be used strictly for suggesting improvements or requesting clarification. Other comments are deleted. If you could bear that in mind, especially considering the volume of comments we get (often 100+ a day), that'd be appreciated ;)

Comment: @ElizB "want to help them financially but without disrespecting their wishes" could be one interpretation, though I'm so desperate to have them get help that I fear I may have to go against their wishes to do so. A thing that I failed to mention in the question is that this person sometimes says rather negative things in relationship to their potential death, such as mentioning how "they going to spend their last months alone". Almost as if they simultaneously want to and don't want to die.

Comment: This is a very difficult situation indeed. However, a word of caution: please don't trust the internet to tell you what you must do. "What should i do" questions are considered off topic. we can only provide ways for you to approach this person to talk about this. We also can't tell you what your friend might say or do as a result of your continuing to ask them to reconsider. I understand your desperate need for an answer,  and empathize with you. Can you edit what you failed to say before into the question and any other pieces of information that might help?

Comment: Also, can you narrow down your question to ask for a more specific goal?

Comment: @ElizB I edited the last sentence with a more specific goal in mind, is this good?

Comment: @anony it's still too broad. If you do decide to do something, the only way IPS can help is to answer questions about what the best approach to the friend about communicating what you did or want to do is.

Comment: @ElizB I'm unsure how else to ask. I realize my question is rather broad, but it's partially because I'm somewhat desperate for any sort of advice. I have no idea where to begin to specify a desperate question like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81425/discussion-between-elizb-and-anony).